What does \vphantom{dlg} do in the tcolorbox documentation?
I tried replicating the inline tcolorbox with a rotated title as shown in the tcolorbox documentation like what was asked in this question.

It is not difficult to find the code, which is shown below.
\newtcbox{\mylib}{enhanced,nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,boxrule=0.4pt,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,
  right=0mm,left=4mm,arc=1pt,boxsep=2pt,before upper={\vphantom{dlg}},
  colframe=green!50!black,coltext=green!25!black,colback=green!10!white,
  overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[green!75!blue!50!white] (frame.south west)
    rectangle node[text=white,font=\sffamily\bfseries\tiny,rotate=90] {LIB} ([xshift=4mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}}}

However, there's one thing that puzzles me. What does before upper={\vphantom{dlg}} do? To be more specific:

Why is a \vphantom needed here?
dlg feels like a magic string, and I want to know how it works.

Thanks!

Welcome to TeX.SE.

What does \vphantom{dlg} do? It inserts a typographic strut with height given by the tips of the letters d and l and depth given by the bottom of the letter g. Not having any psychic connections to the author of the fine tcolorbox matrix, the following is mainly informal speculation. By inserting this strut, one guarantees a minimum height and depth of the framed box. This is particularly useful and desirable if the tcolorbox construct happens to contain a single line that consists of objects such as a, e, v, and z, which don't protrude either above the x-line or the baseline

Thanks, this is really helpful. It's like we chose 3 specific character to cover for all the possible combinations of letters/text. Do these 3 also cover all the scenarios with capitalized letters?

Again, the following is mainly informed (?) speculation: In many fonts, the lowercase letters (such as d and l) are taller than (or at least as tall as) their corresponding uppercase siblings. Hence the use of the “tall” lowercase letters in the argument of \vphantom.

The rotated “LIB” is typeset as an overlay, so it reserves no space.
In the following example I renamed Thomas Sturm's \mylib to \hislib and redefined \mylib without the \vphantom{dlg}.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\hislib}{
  enhanced,
  nobeforeafter,
  tcbox raise base,
  boxrule=0.4pt,
  top=0mm,
  bottom=0mm,
  right=0mm,
  left=4mm,
  arc=1pt,
  boxsep=2pt,
  before upper={\vphantom{dlg}},
  colframe=green!50!black,
  coltext=green!25!black,
  colback=green!10!white,
  overlay={
    \begin{tcbclipinterior}
    \fill[green!75!blue!50!white] (frame.south west) rectangle node[
      text=white,
      font=\sffamily\bfseries\tiny,
      rotate=90
    ] {LIB} ([xshift=4mm]frame.north west);
    \end{tcbclipinterior}
  },
}

\newtcbox{\mylib}{
  enhanced,
  nobeforeafter,
  tcbox raise base,
  boxrule=0.4pt,
  top=0mm,
  bottom=0mm,
  right=0mm,
  left=4mm,
  arc=1pt,
  boxsep=2pt,
%  before upper={\vphantom{dlg}},
  colframe=green!50!black,
  coltext=green!25!black,
  colback=green!10!white,
  overlay={
    \begin{tcbclipinterior}
    \fill[green!75!blue!50!white] (frame.south west) rectangle node[
      text=white,
      font=\sffamily\bfseries\tiny,
      rotate=90
    ] {LIB} ([xshift=4mm]frame.north west);
    \end{tcbclipinterior}
  },
}

\begin{document}

\hislib{test} \mylib{test} \mylib{ace} \mylib{\tiny test}

\hislib{test} \hislib{\tiny test}

\end{document}


The \vphantom ensures that the box will be at least as high and deep as letters with ascenders and descenders (plus the inner spacing, the frame rule width and outer spacing, of course).
Why “dl” when perhaps ”d” might do? Because in some fonts the “l” is higher than the “d”. Better safe than sorry. For the depth, in most fonts the “y” is deeper than “g”, but the difference is usually tiny.
Using \strut wouldn't do as well. If I redefine \mylib to use
before upper=\strut,

the output would become


This explanation is very clear. Thank you!
